# Javascript : The global variables value cannot be changed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, global-variables, scope

```
FB.api(...,function (..){
  var a = 0 ;
  FB.api(...,function (l){
         a = l.data.length;
  });
     alert(a) ;     
});
```

the value of a displayed is zero    !? 
Shouldn't it be Giving a value l.data.length ?! 
If i have alert(a) ;  after the line a = l .data.length ; 
its working :/

### **UPDATE :**

since FB.api is asynchronous is there any any other way to modify a ?

Answer (score 1):

FB api is asynchronous.

If you need to use variable after changing its value, send a callback to the function and get the variable in the callback.

```
var callback = function(){
  alert(a);
}
FB.api(...,function (l, callback){
         a = l.data.length;
         callback();
  });
```

Comment: Hows this different form just havin alert(a) after a=l.data.length ?

Comment: It's exactly the same, but necessary when commands that have to be done on callback will be change on another call of the same function.

Comment: Sorry but i cant understand what you are trying to imply @user123456

Comment: When you have a function doing somthing like
`var sum = function(a, b){ sum = a + b }`
its not correct to add there commands that are not relating to the function. i.e. one time i'm doing alert(sum), one time generalSum += sum. thats why you have to send the wanted command as callback.
`callback1 = function(){alert(sum);}`
`callback2 = function(){generalSum += sum;}`
then i can call the function as i want - 
`sum(1, 2, callback1)`
`sum(1, 2, callback2)`

Comment: BTW, Try not using global variable they are considered bad.

Answer (score 1):

FB api is  asynchronous. so you should alert the value of `a` at your callback function

```
function (l){
     a = l.data.length;
     alert(a);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

its asynchronous;
so by the time

```
function (l){
     a = l.data.length;
})
```

executes alert(a) would already have been executed.

EDIT:
next operation we should write after the variable a has been set in the same function

```
function (l){
     a = l.data.length;
     nextThing1();
     nextThing2()
})
```

Comment: so if i need to change the value of a . what should i do ?

Comment: then next operation should be written after line a = l.data.length within the enclosing function

Comment: what if i need to assign the value to a ; before going to the next line ? or in other wise prevent the next line from executing till the function is over ?

Answer (score 0):

`a = l.data.length` is in the callback function, it will be executed when the callback function is called.

But `alert(a)` will be executed immediately after the `FB.api`.